# map(function, sequence) where function returns two values

Tags: python

Look at the following Python code:

```
def function(x):
    return x, x+1

sequence = range(5)

map(function, sequence)
```

this returns

```
[(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)]
```

I want to get the output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That means, I want to get the two outputs of function into two different lists. Can I achieve this without looping over my lists?

In the real code I will not have lists of integers, but of class instances. So I might get some copy/deepcopy issues, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
>>> a = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)]
>>> zip(*a)
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = zip(*map(function, sequence))
>>> for i in a: print(i)
...
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be:

```
>>> seq = range(5+1)
>>> a = [seq[:-1], seq[1:]]
>>> a
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```